# How to put <h1> element on top of ParticlesJS

Tags: reactjs, particles.js

I'm working on a React application using ParticlesJS on some of my components. For one of my components, I have Particles running and would like to add some text on top of the background. I tried adding it but the text does not show up.

I added my component and css code.

```
render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Particles
                params={{
                    "particles": {
                        "number": {
                        "value": 300,
                        },
                        "color": {
                            "value": "#000000"
                        },
                        "line_linked": {
                            "color": "#000000"
                        },
                        "stroke": {
                            "width": 0,
                            "color": "#000000"
                        },
                        "size": {
                            "value": 3
                        }
                    },
                    "interactivity": {
                        "events": {
                            "onhover": {
                                "enable": true,
                                "mode": "repulse"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "retina_detect": false
                }} >

                <div class="text">

                    <h1>This is a test</h1>

                </div>


                </Particles>

              </>
        );
      }
```

```
.text{
    background-color: black;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 40%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I would the text to show up on top of the Particles background.

Comment: You might want to make sure the [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) property is set correctly, as it might be rendering below the particles.

Comment: If you want to use `z-index`, the elements cannot be nested. They need to be siblings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try o add some **z-index** to text. But my lucky guess would be that **Particles** don't support children component. Instead, put Particles and text inside some wrapper div, something like this:

```
<div className="wrapper">
    <Particles />
    <div className="text">
        <h1>This is a test</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And use CSS similar to this:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.text{
    background-color: black;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 40%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If again you have some issues, add **z-index** to text, and check Particles in Console tools do they have some z-index.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using `react-particles-js`. 
When looking at the code the `Particles` component is not rendering any children but only the canvas. Also in the page DOM the `h1` tag should not be included.

So you have to wrap your particles and your text inside of another component:

```
<div class="container">
   <Particles .../>
   <div class="text">
       <h1>This is a test</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

with

```
.container {
   position: relative;
}
```